# How can I know the password of WiFi stored in my mobile

Tags: security, wifi

I have bunch of WiFi names and passwords stored in my mobile but I want to know their passwords without making my mobile as root. Is there any way I can know that.In future, if I added any new password then can I stored them in separate file behind the scene.
I am using google nexus 4.

Comment: I believe this question belongs on android.stackexchange.com . Regarding the content of the question: I don't think it's possible to do so without root in vanilla Android.

Comment: I have android 5.1.1 installed

Comment: With the term "vanilla" I was referring to the unmodified Android as provided by Google and installed on Nexus devices by default. Thus I don't believe your Android allows you to read the passwords out without rooting the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way, if you can enable ADB (Android Debug Bridge) from the phone settings.

Just you need to do pull the file **/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf** to your pc. Contains the passwords stored.

Tutorial with the steps: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-see-a-saved-Wi-Fi-password-on-Android-without-root-privileges